# MySql query join return result with empty column

Tags: mysql, join

hello i have this query i want it to also return rows from table j(jobcard) where j.articleId,j.statusId,j.hcwsId,j.gpId are null any help plz?

```
SELECT jobcardId,createDateTime,jobNo,companyId,
                         customerId,serialNo,rsvdDate,model,promiseDate,
                         readyDate,deliveryDate,cashMemoNo,dealer,
                         dop,status,warrantyCardno,batchNo,
                         employeeId,hcws,gp,cdId,
                         collectionDate,remarks,article 
                FROM jobcard j, articles a, statuses s, hcws h, gp g
                WHERE j.articleId=a.articleId AND
                      j.statusId = s.statusId AND
                      j.hcwsId = h.hcwsId AND
                      j.gpId=g.gpId"
```

Comment: Do you mean that `jobcard` has actual NULL values, or do you mean that there are no matches for the row in the other tables?

Comment: i mean that i want all rows from jobcard table even if they r null. because initially i dont put ids in jobcard columns(articleid,statusid...)... it only returns rows where these columns are not null

Comment: to be simple i want records where j.articleId=a.articleId and j.articleId= null from jobcard table

Comment: try to read about `LEFT JOIN`. here: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: @RelevantUsername If you don't use a LEFT JOIN, that will perform a cross-product with every row in `articles`, not likely what he wants.

Comment: @RelevantUsername That's why they invented left joins in about 1986 or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not getting `NULL` values for those columns because your inner joins are excluding them - they don't match up with anything in the other tables.

To include nulls, use `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT jobcardId,createDateTime,jobNo,companyId,
  customerId,serialNo,rsvdDate,model,promiseDate,
  readyDate,deliveryDate,cashMemoNo,dealer,
  dop,status,warrantyCardno,batchNo,
  employeeId,hcws,gp,cdId,
  collectionDate,remarks,article 
FROM jobcard j
LEFT OUTER JOIN articles a ON j.articleId=a.articleId
LEFT OUTER JOIN statuses s ON j.statusId = s.statusId
LEFT OUTER JOIN hcws h ON j.hcwsId = h.hcwsId
LEFT OUTER JOIN gp g ON j.gpId=g.gpId
```

Comment: i should hv known this :D thanxxxx (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`. The query you have now effectively works as an `INNER JOIN`, exluding rows where there are no matches. With LEFT JOIN you return all rows from jobcard, and return `NULL` for columns from other tables if they contain no matching records (i.e. when jobcard contains `NULL` for that column).

```
SELECT jobcardId,createDateTime,jobNo,companyId,
                         customerId,serialNo,rsvdDate,model,promiseDate,
                         readyDate,deliveryDate,cashMemoNo,dealer,
                         dop,status,warrantyCardno,batchNo,
                         employeeId,hcws,gp,cdId,
                         collectionDate,remarks,article 
FROM 
  jobcard j
  LEFT JOIN articles a on j.articleId=a.articleId
  LEFT JOIN statuses s on j.statusId = s.statusId
  LEFT JOIN hcws h j.hcwsId = h.hcwsId 
  LEFT JOIN gp g on j.gpId=g.gpId
```